# Why does webpack create require('react') for my client-side code

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following `webpack.config.js` :

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

const jsLoader = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: ['env', 'react'],
    plugins: ['babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread']
  }
}

const client = {
  entry: ['./app/client.js'],
  output: {
    path: '/public',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'client.bundle.js'
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
     loaders: [jsLoader]
  }
}

module.exports = [client]
```

and the result `client.bundle.js`:

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("react");
```

It fails, in chrome, because `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

On my `client.js`, I'm importing react, react-dom, prop-types, and some react components.

Why does webpack, for react and prop-types, does a `require`, instead of a `__webpack_require__` like it does for other require ?

React@16.2,
Webpack@3.10
Node@8.4

Thanks,

Comment: If this is your production build I don't understand why you use `webpack-node-externals` (this thing makes all this magic with `require`). It's useful for libraries, but not for bundled apps. If you need to run your bundle in a browser then just bundle your code with dependencies. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

So,

As Wostex said, my problem came from node externals.

When I remove it, `npm build` take a long time and fail on some winston, fs, readMe files, etc...

It seems that the custom logger module I'm using was importing modules that does not fit for browser. So i'm still using externals, but removing this logger.